# WIndow.name not setting window name in a way that target identifies

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, href

**My use case:**

- User already has web app open in a browser tab
- An email is sent to the user with an anchor tag that takes user to a specific page in the web app
- On clicking, the initial tab is repopulated with new page

To do this the anchor tag is formatted like `<a target="webapp" href="example.com" >Click Here</a>` and I have a tiny bit of javascript, triggered on load, in my web app like this `window.name="webapp"`

**What is working:**

- If I test to make sure the window name was with `window.name="webapp"`, doing `console.log(window.name)`, it confirms that it was
- If I click the link from the email and the web app isn't open yet a new tab opens. If I click that link again the tab that initially opened refreshes.

**What isn't work:**
If the user initially navigates directly to the web app (not via a link) and then clicks the link from the email, the link opens a new tab instead of repopulating the open tab. In this scenario I still get the correct window name in the console log but not the functionality I'm looking for.

Looking for insight into how to get this to work or if there's a better solution to this use case.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with JavaScript...

Comment: I've found references to it being possible, but if it isn't, I'm open to alternitive workflows.